# IntelliJ gives Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath

Tags: intellij-idea, classpath

When I try to make a simple module in IntelliJ it responds with:

```
Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath
```

Answer (score 257, accepted):

Somehow the JDK language jars were removed from the classpath. All I had to do was reapply the JSDK home path.

Goto: 
File -> Project Structure -> Platform Settings -> SDKs
Re-apply the JSDK home path.

Doing this added about 15 jars to the classpath. Apparently these are important for compiling.

Comment: Thanks, I just ran in to this and your fix worked for me as well.  I somehow triggered the issue when adding and removing some SDKs (I have multiple versions of the JDK installed on my machine).

Comment: I think this happened when I added the same jdk again. It removed all of the references from the original jdk :/

Comment: I didn't change anything with my IDE or SDK but system updates may have touched that.  Re-applying the JSDK home path worked.  Thanks!

Comment: JetBrains should fix this lame bug.

Comment: I've run into this with IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.3, so not fixed, yet

Comment: Just hit this in 13.1.4, still not fixed. Thank you for the workaround.

Comment: for reapplying the JSDK, I had to remove and add it again

Comment: Confirmed this bug still exists, version 14.1.4

Comment: @FreeDevz stumbled across the same error, but looks like the menu options have changed, can not find platform settings and SDKs options in the project structure ! Any idea where to find this resetting of JSDK ?

Comment: What do you mean by "reapplying". I removed my old JSDK and added it again, but it does not work. I am using Java 2016.3

Comment: Also if there are still errors, you could goto project settings > project and point 'project SDK' to added SDK

Comment: Just caught this bug in Idea 2017.3.2. Reapplied jdk by hittling path selecting button (with 3 dots on button caption) and selecting again the same path to JDK.

Comment: Reporting from year 2018, with IDEA Ultimate 2017.3.4, the bug is still alive and well :) Reapplying it once after installation in Ubuntu was sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, Applying JDK home path again, helped

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3 (Community Edition) - problem still exists. Your tip helped me, thanks!

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.3 (Ultimate Edition) problem still exists, thanks.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.1 problem still exists

Comment: (btw, it is happening to me even when calling gradle from terminal in a specific project here. So, at least in my case, it is more probable that it is some gradle config in the project or the fact that this project's gradle version is pre-historic. So if you are using gradle also, watch out for this possibility. Reapply here didn't work of course.)

Comment: yes, problem still occurs

Answer (score 21):

File -> Project Structure -> Platform Settings -> SDKs, remove existing SDK and add it again.

Works for me in IntelliJ 2017.3.

Comment: This problem happened to me once after upgrading jdk (only the patch number),  removing and adding again did make everything compile again.

Answer (score 13):

This error happend to me after i've updated my JDK version to jdk1.8.0_161 - 
But the project's sdk was still pointing to the old jdk 1.8.0_**131**

(Seems that updgrading java causing the previous version to be wiped).

**Do this:**

1. In the IntelliJ IDE go to File > Project Structure, from there:
2. Within `Platform Settings > SDKs`:
   Make sure that the JDK Home path field is pointing to a valid JDK folder (add a new entry if needed e.g. jdk1.8.0_161).
3. Within `Project Settings > Modules`: 
   Make sure that the Module SDK is set to the same entry you picked in the `Platform Settings > SDKs`
4. Save & Build again.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

In Preferences `Build Tools > Maven > Runner > Environment Variables` set `JAVA_HOME` to your JDK home path.

Usually you want to use the same Java JDK you are using in IntelliJ. You can find that under `Project Structure > Platform Settings > SDKs` under `JDK home path`.

e.g. `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_66.jdk/Contents/Home`

Answer (score 4):

In Intellij Community 2019.1, this is what I did to solve the issue

- Project Structure > Platform Settings > SDKs
- Removed all existing SDKs listed ( I had multiple SDK listed there)
- Add the required SDK only and Apply

Answer (score 1):

1. File > Project Structure
2. JDK home path : PASTE_THE_JDK_LOCATION (Like here in the "[Project Structure screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVLjw.png)"
3. Build Again

   Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

After following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25464621/197574) answer,
I learned that `%LOCALAPPDATA%/IDEA/config/options/jdk.table.xml` contained incorrect entries. Fixing the JDK table fixed the problem.