# how to configure android build path?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've had to install java, eclipse and android on a new machine as my old one had a problem with the graphics card. i've downloaded some software and others i've dragged in from my old harddrive, which is now an external harddrive. when i import the project i was working on from my old machine eclipse cant resolve anything that is android eg Activity, WindowManager etc. i've added android\tools and platform-tools to my system's path. In Eclipse when i try to configure the project's build path i've noticed that in the libraries tab it states "unable to get system library for the project". the only thing i've done differently on this installation is use jdk1.7.0 opposed to jdk6 on the old machine. any ideas on how to resolve this?

thanks matt.

Comment: I know it's for IntelliJ, but possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943537/java-7-intellij/6952093#comment-8560913

Answer (score 0):

find default.properties,modify the **default-version**,then,modify the Jdk **1.7 to 1.6**,try step by step.the reason maybe is the Compatibility。