# Android javadoc, com.sun.tools.javac.util.FatalError: Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath

Tags: java, android

I am trying to generate my project doc , and got an error on a java.lang

```
Loading source files for package com.swimtechtest.swimmer...
Loading source files for package com.swimtechtest.swimmer.math...
Loading source files for package com.swimtechtest.swimmer.database...
Loading source files for package com.swimtechtest.swimmer.helpers...
Constructing Javadoc information...
com.sun.tools.javac.util.FatalError: Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.importAll(MemberEnter.java:123)
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.visitTopLevel(MemberEnter.java:509)
at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCCompilationUnit.accept(JCTree.java:446)
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.memberEnter(MemberEnter.java:387)
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.complete(MemberEnter.java:819)
at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.complete(Symbol.java:384)
at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.complete(Symbol.java:766)
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:464)
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:442)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.JavadocEnter.main(JavadocEnter.java:53)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.JavadocTool.getRootDocImpl(JavadocTool.java:152)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.parseAndExecute(Start.java:330)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:128)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(Main.java:41)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.main(Main.java:31)
javadoc: error - fatal error
1 error
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [FatalError while creating javadoc (Unable to find package java.lang)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20272715/fatalerror-while-creating-javadoc-unable-to-find-package-java-lang)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1) remove spaces from the path to android.jar (all the fixes I tried to allow it to work with spaces didn't work for me)

2) Choose Project/Generate Javadoc...

3) Enter correct path to the javadoc executable, which, in my case looked like this:

[image]

4) Click next and enter a document title

5) Click next and add bootclasspath to the VM options. I did a search on my mac to find the android.jar. Make sure you use the correct location and version. Mine looked like this:

[image]

6) Click finish and it should work.

Hope that helps :-)