# JavaDoc generation in Android Studio: NullPointerException

Tags: nullpointerexception, android-studio, javadoc

When trying to generate JavaDoc in Android Studio, it acts up and shows countless errors concerning non-existing packages and unknown symbols (mostly Android-related stuff).

Finally I get this error message:

```
Standard Doclet version 1.7.0_55
Building tree for all the packages and classes...
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.TypeMaker.getType(TypeMaker.java:83)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.TypeMaker.getType(TypeMaker.java:44)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.ClassDocImpl.superclassType(ClassDocImpl.java:496)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.Util.getAllInterfaces(Util.java:459)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.Util.getAllInterfaces(Util.java:497)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.ClassTree.processType(ClassTree.java:194)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.ClassTree.buildTree(ClassTree.java:146)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.ClassTree.<init>(ClassTree.java:91)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.startGeneration(AbstractDoclet.java:123)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.start(AbstractDoclet.java:83)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDoclet.start(HtmlDoclet.java:63)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.standard.Standard.start(Standard.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.invoke(DocletInvoker.java:280)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.start(DocletInvoker.java:160)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.parseAndExecute(Start.java:397)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:167)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.main(Main.java:49)
342 warnings

javadoc exited with exit code 1
```

Comment: There is a unresolved issue at android issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63249

Comment: This fixed for me. Hope it helps!

[Generate Javadoc error Android Studio][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24296210/generate-javadoc-error-android-studio

Comment: fixed by setting the "Other command line arguments" (which really should have been set by the IDE !!) see http://stackoverflow.com/a/27939858/550471

Answer (score 0):

Once you are in javadoc generation wizard

1. Check include jdk and library sources
2. Add this line in front of `Other command line arguments`

   ```
   -encoding utf-8 -bootclasspath /path/to/sdk/platforms/android-##/android.jar
   ```